# Is it possible to customize http connection when updating RCP application?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

For example add some headers, or cookies to connection? I found that they are using 
org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfor.httpclient and it use org.apache.commons.httpclient plugin for connection, but it is possible to 'hook' somehow there?

Comment: Why do you want to try do that?

Comment: SSO(single sign on) for example